# Regression Using Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, bioinformatics, linear-regression, caffe

I have 900 training samples and 100 test samples where each of the samples has one label (e.g. 64, 136 so on). Here each sample is represented with a 1-dimensional vector of size 460000.

## How can I do linear regression using CAFFE with these data? I badly need  a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  With all the documentation and examples available on line, your research should have brought you to a point where you have code to post and a specific difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Euclidean layer as loss function.
[Euclidean Loss Layer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1EuclideanLossLayer.html).

With that, just make sure your last layer has only one neuron output (num_output: 1, in your protoxt file).

You can check some examples here: [Examples Caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/mnist), particularly the Autoencoder uses fully connected network and the Euclidean loss.

Comment: Following this suggestion I trained my network. But the network always producing the same output. It seems the network is not learning.  Can you please tell me how can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: It is hard to know without further details, you should check if the loss is decreasing during training, and other factors. However, if the network is always producing the same output, maybe there is something wrong on how you read the data in the last layer? You can always check the outputs layer by layer and find out what can be going on...